# Padded display of data in array of arrays in table

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, html-table, date-fns

Let's say I have an array of arrays containing JavaScript Date Objects, grouped by day.
How would I go about displaying them in HTML as a table (or any other way), so that all matching times are on the same height?
Array:

```
let array = [
    [
        new Date("2020-01-01 08:00:00"),
        new Date("2020-01-01 08:30:00"),
        new Date("2020-01-01 09:00:00")
    ],
    [
        new Date("2020-01-02 08:30:00"),
        new Date("2020-01-02 09:00:00"),
        new Date("2020-01-02 09:30:00")
    ],
    [
        new Date("2020-01-04 09:00:00"),
        new Date("2020-01-03 10:00:00")
    ]
]
```

Desired output as HTML table:

```
|-------|-------|-------|
| 08:00 |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 08:30 | 08:30 |       |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 09:00 | 09:00 | 09:00 |
|-------|-------|-------|
|       | 09:30 |       |
|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       | 10:00 |
|-------|-------|-------|
```

Just for displaying the data, I'd simply use two nested `foreach` loops but then I would end up with all rows starting in the first, not padding as anticipated.
I am using `Date-Fns` so I suppose I could use `getHours(date)` somehow to compare two dates and if they should be on the same height.

Are there any simple solutions to do this?